# Users upgrading from Parse.com to new Parser Server in Android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

So with parse shutting down, im looking to update my backend to use the parse server. My question is, if i switch the the parse server, will there be any interruptions for my users?  Will they continue to get data, or will they need to upgrade fist?

Comment: Well, they'll presumably need to point their devices to your server instead of parse cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration should be invisible to your users.  As stated in the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App), you do not need to switch the end points until you have fully tested your backend. So there will be a time where you will have data in both parse servers and your servers.

Once you are satisfied with your backend, you'll need to push an update to the app pointing to your parse servers instead of parse.com server.

Answer (score 1):

When you will release an updated version of the app on App Store, they will have to update their app to the latest version. The older version of the app on app store that is still pointing to api.parse.com will stop working when Parse goes down. Other than that the users won't see any difference in the functionality of the app